# How to read the incoming message using service in background in android?

Tags: android, sms

I am developing an android application in that i want to read the incoming message without knowing the user.I want to always run the incoming message checker in background.If a new message is received means i want to read the content of the message and that message contains some words(password) means i want to activate the application

Please explain me how to do that with sample code because i am new to android

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look at BroadCastReceivers you must implement and register a Reciever for `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`

Here is a code snippet that lets you read messages as they arrive.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage [] messages = null;
        String strMessage = "";

        if (myBundle != null)
        {
            Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
            {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                strMessage += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                strMessage += " : ";
                strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                strMessage += "\n";
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And here what you have to add to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: I don't think, your code will work as a service, here is same issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029040/how-to-run-an-android-app-in-background

Comment: this is not a service.