# Read incoming message till verification sms is read

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I m looking to add sms reading functionality in my app. The user enters his mobile number in an activity and then a sms containing one time password is sent to the user mobile phone from the server. What I want to do is trigger the app to read incoming messages after the user has entered the mobile number and is expecting incoming message from the server.

I have seen some questions like this answered here 
[How to read the incoming message using service in background in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973985/how-to-read-the-incoming-message-using-service-in-background-in-android)

but the solution seems to be reading all the sms that come on the phone. In my case I just want the reading functionality to start only when user is expecting a sms and end when the message has been received.

Answer (score 1):

check this answer that show you how to register a receiver
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049747/774944

```
final String SOME_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SOME_ACTION);
SMSReceiver mReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver,intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable broadcast receivers at run time using package manager.

```
public void enableSmsModule()
{
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SMSReceiver.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public void disableSmsModule()
{
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SMSReceiver.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Code for reading sms : [How to read the incoming message using service in background in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973985/how-to-read-the-incoming-message-using-service-in-background-in-android)